# simple Request To a Servers Symfomny2

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

I am trying to implement the infinite scroll option in Sympfony2.

Controller:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{ 
    if (!$request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        return $this->render(
            'UsuarioBundle:Default:index.html.twig'
        );
    } else {
        return new Response("Ajax ok");
    }
}
```

jquery

```
$(function(){
    var data={
            type:'1'                           
};
    var i = 0;
  $(window).scroll(function(){
   //cuando llegas al final de la página
    if (document.body.scrollHeight - $(this).scrollTop() <= $(this).height()){
            agregarContenido();
        }
    });
  function agregarContenido(){
        //Agregar el siguiente contenido a mostrar
        var path = "/";
         $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      dataType :   'json',
      data: data,
      url:  path,
    success: function(response) {
          console.log(response);
      }
    });
    }
});
```

and Routing.yml

```
index:
path:    /
    defaults:  { _controller: UsuarioBundle:Default:index }
```

The code doesn't work, it never prints "ajax ok". but Ajax requests are always sent to server when I did scrolling.

My Question is, how can i print "ajax ok" in the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dataType` you specified in your JS presents a problem. Your controller return `Response` object which is plain `HTML` but your JS counterpart expects `json`, so that won't work.

Try setting `dataType` to `html`...

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you should make

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

public function indexAction(Request $request)
{ 
    if (!$request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        return $this->render(
            'UsuarioBundle:Default:index.html.twig'
        );
    } else {
        $response = new JsonResponse();
        $response->setData(array(
            'status' => 1,
            'result' => 'Ajax ok'
        ));

        return $response;

    }
}
```